# How do I make my element inherit width & height?

Tags: html

Stackers. I'm trying to get my box class to actually become a box. I want the box class to have a height and width of 10em of the  font-size. So for instance the boxes should have heights and widths of 12px * 10 em.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<!--
     Your name does here
     The date goes here
     CISC 131

     A short description of the project goes here
-->
<html lang="en">
<head>
<title>this will appear on the tab in the browser</title>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
<script src="tictactoe.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<style type="text/css">
*{
    border  : 0;
    margin  : 0;
    padding : 0;
}

body
{
    font-family : "Times New Roman";
    font-size   : 12px;
    width       : 33em;
    padding-top : 5em;
    text-align  : center;
    margin-left : auto;
    margin-right: auto;
}
.square
{
    font-size   : 8em;
    text-align  : center;
    float       : left;
    height      : 10em;
    width       : 10em;
    background-color: red;
}

</style>

</head>
<body>
<div id="gameBoard">
<div class"square" id="box0">dwda</div>
<div class"square" id="box1">wadawd</div>
<div class"square" id="box2"></div>
<div class"square" id="box3"></div>
<div class"square" id="box4"></div>
<div class"square" id="box5"></div>
<div class"square" id="box6"></div>
<div class"square" id="box7"></div>
<div class"square" id="box8"></div>
<div id="ticTacToeBoard"></div>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: and what do you observe instead?

Comment: When I click inspect element my boxes has a width of 396(12*33) but a height of 0. Each of the boxes should be 44 by 44 px (396/9 = 44)

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend you to use same measure units, either px or em.
I have made a small [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/y04u5Lcg/4/) with your sizes. I've set font-size to 1em and box size to 10em.

The gameBoard calculation is:

```
3*10em + 2em (margin-right for all but last in row) = 32em
```

Is this what you were trying to do?

Comment: This is an assignment for class and he basically says it's a requirement that we use em. I have no idea how this is possible.

Comment: This solution is in em.

Comment: So if I understand you correct, why wouldn't you use font-size of 1em? I've updated the fiddle.